# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes while background upload

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, freeze

My new **Ubuntu 18.04 installation freeze** sometimes, at first I can't figure out the issue but now I know that when any background upload task initiated it gets freezes. I have experienced it with the following.

1. Google drive upload in chrome
2. Playing plex media content locally on my android.
3. When deluge starts downloading torrents.
4. Any uploading activity in browser, chrome or firefox.

I can't do my other work until it finishes uploading, I can barely move my mouse pointer, I googled everywhere but can't find a solution.
Any help will be appreciated.